# How to pull a range of values from a four-dimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a four dimensional array

To access one value from my array I would use the following code:

```
$class = $schedule[$week][$day][$room][$hour];
```

I would like to be able to pull all the values for a specific week, day, and hour for a range of rooms into a smaller array without restructuring my array.

I was thinking something like:

```
$classes = $schedule[$week][$day][range(1,10)][$hour];
```

How would I achieve something like this?

Comment: What would you have the result be? A Sum of the hours? An array of hours items?

Comment: Traverse `$schedule[$week][$day]`, check the key (the room) to fit your cirteria and if so, store `$schedule[$week][$day][%current-key%][$hour]` to your result set.

Comment: I would want an array of the classes assigned to rooms 1-10 for that specific week, day, and hour.

Comment: Will you always have a consistent range of values to check, or will it be a selection of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if it's what you want:

```
for($i=1;$i<=10;++$i){
   echo $schedule[$week][$day][$i][$hour];
}
```

that will echo room from 1 to 10

you can also store the 10 room in `Array` like:

```
    for($i=1;$i<=10;++$i){
     $classes[] = $schedule[$week][$day][$i][$hour];
    }
```

Comment: This would work, but I was hoping to do it without another for-loop if possible:
for($i=1;$i<=10;++$i){
    $classes[] = $schedule[$week][$day][$i][$hour];
}

Comment: @user1370238 see updated anwser, you can do `$classes[] = $schedule[$week][$day][$i][$hour]; `

Answer (score 1):

if it is always a range you can use :

```
$classes = array();
for($current_room = 1; $current_room <= 10; $current_room++){
  $classes[$week][$day][$current_room] = $class[$week][$day][$current_room][$hour];
}
```

If you want to be able to use some specific room numbers

```
$classes = array();
foreach(array(1,2,6,8) as $current_room){
  $classes[$week][$day][$current_room] = $class[$week][$day][$current_room][$hour];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right:

```
$classes = array();

for($a=1; $a<=10; $a++){
    $classes[$week][$day][$a][$hour] = $schedule[$week][$day][$a][$hour];
}
```

or

```
$classes = array();    

while($a<11){
    $classes[$week][$day][$a][$hour] = $schedule[$week][$day][$a][$hour];
    $a++;
}
```